# Self Generating Function?

Tags: javascript

Is this possible and if so how? (I haven't been able to find a way for it to work)

```
var foo = function() 
{ 
    console.log("Original Function");
    this = function() 
    {
        console.log("New Function");
    }
};
console.log("Calling foo()");
foo();
```

Desired output:

> Original Function
>
> Calling foo()
>
> New Function

To answer the questions in advance, yes I know there are other ways to do this. I'm just curious if I could do something like `var bar = new foo();` and have `foo()` assign some time dependent properties to itself without an extra function.

**EDIT: Response to Charmanders question, and a slightly less simplified, more practical application**

```
var node = function(parent)
{
    this = function()
    {
        for (i in this)
        {
            // perform actions (which will occasionally include calling i()
        }
    }
    if (parent !== null)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        // code to determine children
        this.somechild = new node(this);
        this.someotherchild = new node(this);
    }
};
var ancestor = new node(new node(null));
```

Comment: Your example seems to be only loosely related to your question. Could you please state exactly what it is you would like to accomplish, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a new value to `this` will not work, but you can simply return a function:

```
var foo = function() { 
    console.log("Original Function");
    return function() {
        console.log("New Function");
    };
};

console.log("Calling foo()");
var f = foo(); /* or even: f = new foo(); */
f();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this technique, you need to assign to the outer function variable directly:

```
var foo = function() 
{ 
    console.log("Original Function");
    foo = function() 
    {
        console.log("New Function");
    };
};
```

If the function shouldn't know where it's stored so that multiple independent copies of the function can exist, then you really want to use a closure factory:

```
function makeReplacingFunction() {
    var fn;

    fn = function() {
        console.log("Original Function");
        fn = function() {
            console.log("New Function");
        };
    };

    return function() { fn(); }
}

var foo = makeReplacingFunction();
foo();
foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you don't do it by assigning to `this`:

```
function foo() {
  console.log("original");
  foo = function() {
    console.log("new");
  };
}
```

All that's doing is assigning a new value to the global symbol "foo", such that the new value happens to be a function.

Thus when you call `foo()` twice, it'll print "original" the first time and "new" every time thereafter.

The value of `this` is usually not the value of the function in which it's referenced; it *can* be, but you'd sort of have to set up a somewhat unusual situation.  Even if it were, you can't assign a new value to `this`.

Comment: that looks like it could clobber the original function though (which may or not be an issue)?

Comment: @MattWhipple I'm under the impression that clobbering the original function is exactly what the OP intends. I could be wrong, but I can't imagine what else could happen to give the desired effects described.